# Populate Accoridon from SQL Database Values

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, accordion

I am creating an accordion that will be populated from a sql database. For example if the database has 5 records (title and description included) then the accordion would have 5 panels. The title bound to the panel title field and the body consisting of the of the description. Like the following image:

[image]

Here is what I have so far by using a DataList and adding the accordion to the item template.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DynamicAccordion" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <!--items in here are rendered once for the entire table and can be title, etc...)    -->
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a runat="server" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Section") %>' ID="SectionTitle"></asp:Label>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <a runat="server" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>' ID="Description"></asp:Label>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <!--Same as the header template just the footer-->
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And here is the backend that would bind the accordion to the sql records:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

}

private void LoadData()
{
    var data = DataAccess.GetCurrentProject();


    try
    {
        //data.Columns.Add("hrefPath");
        foreach (DataRow dr in data.Rows)
        {
            dr["SectionTitle"] = dr["Section"];
            dr["Description"] = dr["Description"];
        }
        DynamicAccordion.DataSource = data;
        DynamicAccordion.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

//Data Access class code
       public static DataTable GetCurrentProject()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                string sqlCommandText = "Select * FROM RequestData";
                using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(strConn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommandText, connect))
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Any information to help in creating this dynamic accordion would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You're not saying what kind of errors, if any, that you're getting with your current code...

Comment: @matt, there is no error. The accordion just doesn't display. Which led me to believe that I wasn't looping through each record and displaying the values from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for each loop in the aspx file to do this:
(Remember you will also need to append to your ID fields to make them unique, otherwise you will end up with duplicates)

```
<% foreach (DataRow dr in data.Rows) { %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a runat="server" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <%= dr["Section"] %>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                     <a runat="server" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <%= dr["Description"] %>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. In this case would I replace the data list with what the foreach loop you added?

Comment: the concept here is that the for each loop will add all of the contained html elements to the page on every iteration (i.e. 4 loop iterations = 4 accordion items).
In your case, you would have the html for an accordion item inside the loop - I've taken a guess at it above. So you would put the loop inside your panel group.